# Windows 7, enabeling IE for removal

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, control-panel

For a while now, Windows Update has been prompting me to update IE9 to IE10. And every time I turn off my PC, It starts to install that one update wich allways fails. Why does it fail updating IE9? I don't know. So the solution I had in my mind was to remove IE9 and then install IE10 manually. THe problem is now, I can't find the uninstall file for IE9. I have looked in *windows control panel / programs and features* but it didn't show up, not even in the *installed updates* section. So after I clicked on *Turn windows features on or off*, I saw that the IE9 box wasn't checked. So I checked it, clicked OK, but then when I clicked on the *Turn windows features on or off* link again, it wasn't checked anymore.

It's almost like Windows doesn't want me to uninstall IE9. but I have to in order to normally shut down my pc, because everytime I shut my PC off, it tries to install that stupid update again!

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Look into your `C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log` logfile to see what the actual problem is.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, you can't remove IE on Windows. You can just downgrade it to lower version. more help?
Basically, IE 10 was designed for Windows 8 and later but now you can install it on Windows 7.
Go to address: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie-10-worldwide-languages
Then download the IE 10 and install it directly. I did that work and now have IE 10 on my Windows 7 32-bit. For any more help just ask.

Comment: IE can be removed through *Programs and Features* -> *Turn Windows features on or off*. Trident libraries are left for applications that use them, but IE gets removed.

Comment: @gronostaj IE **precisely** is these libraries. The option there removes only the fronted (iexplore.exe) which contains little actual code.

Comment: @gronostaj: That feature as it's clear from its name is just a feature  that only on/off the IE. And If you want to use the IE, you should turn it on. You can't remove IE in Windows OS.

Comment: Guys, you can't browse Internet with Trident DLLs, you need `iexplore`. Shared DLLs aren't anything unusual or abnormal and telling that you can't remove an app because some DLLs will be left for other apps is just wrong IMO. Many apps use `mshtml.dll`, are they unremovable too?

Comment: If I can't remove IE to reinstall it later and fix the problem, what CAN I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Now do you have (that is, can you browse with it the Internet?) IE (any version) on your PC or not? If yes, and it's the IE 9, so go to the above link and download desired one. Then install it over IE 9. If there was any problem when installing post it.

Comment: Well the launcher launches, a window with a progress bar pops up saying "downloading required updates ... ", and then after downloading it reports that an error has occured and puts a shortcut to this on my desktop: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2820688

Comment: Go to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2818833 and download the update package number "2670838" (X86). First install it then restart your PC and then try to install IE 10.